# Drag and drop to text box inside a usercontrol not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox and button inside usercontrol. The usercontrol is inside the ContentControl of the main window

```
<TextBox x:Name="FilePathTextBox" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="{Binding SurfaceFile, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="150"
                     AllowDrop="True"  PreviewDragEnter="TextBox_PreviewDragEnter" PreviewDragOver="TextBox_PreviewDragEnter" PreviewDrop="TextBox_PreviewDrop"></TextBox>
```

I have the following code in xaml.cs

```
        private string[] allowedFileExtensions = { ".XML", ".TXT"};

        bool Is_AllowedFile(string fileExtension)
        {
            return allowedFileExtensions.Contains(fileExtension, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }


        private void TextBox_PreviewDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            bool dropEnabled = true;

            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, true))
            {
                string[] droppedFilePaths = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

                if (droppedFilePaths.Count() > 1 || !Is_AllowedFile(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(droppedFilePaths[0])))
                    dropEnabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                dropEnabled = false;
            }

            if (!dropEnabled)
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void TextBox_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] droppedFilePaths = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

                FilePathTextBox.Text = droppedFilePaths[0];
            }
        }
```

The TextBox_PreviewDrop is never getting fired.
Is this implementation correct or there is a better/simple solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked that you're getting the data format correctly in PreviewDragEnter and that you're not disabling the drop?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to drag the text file and it shows the full path of the text file.

Comment: Try setting e.Handled to false at the beginning of PreviewDragEnter. BTW, it's quite possible that if you only need to drag in a string, TextBox can handle it on its own with no need to handle events in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your condition at the end of PreviewDragEnter handler to:

```
if (dropEnabled)
{           
  e.Effects = DragDropEffects.All;
  e.Handled = true;
}
```